# String manipulation (Java)

Tags: java, string

This is my problem: I have a string, which is an expression. This expression contains numerical constants, variables, mathematical & logical operators. For example: 4*A&&B , X+5>Y.
Also, I have a translation map (String->String), which basically translates variables.

Needed output is the translated expression.
Simple replace fails due to this example: expression is A&&X where A -> XX, X->B. Simple replace, starting with A, causes the expression to be XX&&X and then when replacing X I get BB&B, where the expected output should be XX&B.

Any suggestions?

Edit: I guess a possible solution can be to write an expression compiler that will know to parse the expression into atomic units, whom later I can replace. I'm just wondering if there's a simpler solution

Comment: Split you string to list of variables/operators and then replace each variable using your translation map.

Comment: Simple split is not that trivial - some variables can be sub strings of different variables. How can the split be performed?

Comment: If you don't want to split, is it possible to create another StringBuffer to store your parsed result? Using an offset flag to point to the current position in the expression and once the variable/operator is replaced, stored it into the buffer and move the offset. And if a variable can be part of another, your replacement should be either greedy or Reluctant.

Comment: You can try `StringTokenizer` with delimeters: `"+*/-&|"`. I think you'll get all variables and also operators. The problem is operator `&&` will be split into 2 different tokens but you can merge them manually later.

Answer (score 0):

Define "simpler solution".

Parsing the expression into atomic units (to be able to restore the operators, don't use `String.split()` - use `Pattern` and `Matcher` instead (from `java.util.regex`)) is simple and will work.

To be more efficient, you'll have to write a lexical analyzer of some sort, and there flies the simplicity out the window.